# Making this method Generic with variable parameter

Tags: c#

Is there any creative way to make this method Generic, I hate having to copy-paste it everywhere:

```
private CoachContext GetMockContext(Mock<DbSet<LastViewedRecord>> mockSet) {
  var autoFixture = new Fixture();
  DbContextOptions<CoachContext> options = autoFixture
    .Build<DbContextOptions<CoachContext>>()
    .Create();
  var mockContext = new Mock<CoachContext>(options);
  mockContext.Setup(c => c.LastViewedRecords).Returns(mockSet.Object);
  return mockContext.Object;
}
```

I can make the `LastViewedRecord` into `T` and make the method Generic, but I cannot get around `c => c.LastViewedRecords`

**Solution:** I changed the method signature to something like this:

```
protected CreditCoachContext GetMockContext<T>(
  IQueryable<T> mockData,
  Expression<Func<CreditCoachContext,
  DbSet<T>>> contextExpression
) where T : class
```

Comment: You want to pas in the function right?

Comment: c is a DbContext ? - You can use .Set<T>() to get the set from a type if so?

Comment: I'd like to pass "LastViewedRecords" into the function yes.

Comment: make a base object such as DatabaseModel that has LastViewedRecords, then use <T> where implements

Comment: The statement `c => c.LAstViewedRectors` is a function that takes a type and returns a type -- define those types and add the function as a parameter to your generic function, then you will put `c => c.LAstViewedRectors` when you call your funciton.  You can looks at the definition of mackContext.Setup 1st param to see what type needs to be passed to your funciton

Comment: Is `c => c.LastViewedRecords` a `Func` or `Expression`?

Comment: @Hogan - I'm asking what the concrete type is, lambdas can be compiled into either `Func`s or `Expression`s which is going to be needed if you want to make it a parameter.

Comment: @Lee --- Right we need to see the definition of `mockContest.Setup`'s first parameter -- whatever that is would be used in the generic function

Comment: Setup takes an expression parameter

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, your hints led me to a solution. Will update question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this might help. (PS: I am not sure about `Fixture`)

```
private TReturn GetMockContext<TContext, TEntity, TReturn>(Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> mockSet, 
  Expression<Func<CreditCoachContext>> contextExpression) 
    where TContext : DbContext, new() 
    where TEntity : class 
    where TReturn : class
{
  var autoFixture = new Fixture();
  DbContextOptions<TContext> options = autoFixture
    .Build<DbContextOptions<TContext>>()
    .Create();
  var mockContext = new Mock<TContext>(options);
  mockContext.Setup(contextExpression).Returns(mockSet.Object);
  return mockContext.Object;
}
```

Comment: I believe you need 'where' on every line, but I like this. Generic all things!

Comment: I fixed it :) Thanks for the comment